# Word Add-in not appearing in MS Store on Mac

Tags: office-js, word-addins

We have a Word add-in on the AppSource store, but when we try to install it via Word on Mac, the add-in does not appear in the store.

Link to the app:
https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000668

Word Version:
16.36 (20041300)

The only requirement set for the application is WordApi 1.1, which should be supported on Mac:

```
<Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
</Sets>
```

The add-in works perfectly fine on Mac when side-loaded.

Any idea why the add-in is not appearing in the store?

Thanks,

Morgan

Comment: I can repro this issue, looks like a bug, i would suggest that you could also report this issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues, therefore someone could help from team

Comment: I created the following issue:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1136